# Plot a Line Chart Without Using Core Plot Library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, charts

Is there any other Library to draw Chart in iphone with any example. Because I found that Core Plot is too Complex & i also download some controls from Github, But they are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer here nice examples and libraries : http://maniacdev.com/2011/08/open-source-plotting-libraries-for-easy-charts-without-the-cost/

Answer (score 2):

Why not create your own API using Core Graphics & quartz core?

Some charting libraries other than core plot are:

1> http://sebkade.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/basic-graph-class-for-iphone/

2> http://www.vvi.com/apps/vvidget

3>  http://www.rgraph.net/

4> http://www.keepedge.com/products/iphone_charting/

5>  http://www.shinobicontrols.com/

Still its better to use core animation, core graphics and quartz core to create your own graphs.